# What is the value of `self` in routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need some help understanding the following `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
end
```

From my understanding of Ruby this line:

```
get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
```

is the same as:

```
self.get('help' => 'static_pages#help')
```

Then what in this case is the value of `self`?

Comment: You could just a call to `puts self.inspect` to find out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` in `routes.rb` is an instance of [`ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper.html).

You can simply check it by putting

```
raise self.inspect
```

in your `routes.rb` and running

```
rails server
```

Visit the localhost and you'll see something like this:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000000062598a0 @set=#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x00000003d59500>,@scope=#<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x00000006259850 @hash={:path_names=>{:new=>"new", :edit=>"edit"}}, @parent={}, @scope_level=nil>, @concerns={}, @nesting=[]>
```